# Map two data class as object with list of objects

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, jdbi

```
data class Sample
@JdbiConstructor constructor(
    val time: ZonedDateTime,
    val name: String,
    val id;

)

data class OtherSample
@JdbiConstructor constructor(
    val sampleId: Long,
    val value2: Long,
    val value3: Long,
)
```

Then I have two JDBI functions to get "Sample" and "Other Sample. I need to create third class, `ResultDto`, which looks like:

```
data class ResultDto(
    val time: ZonedDateTime,
    val name: String,
    val list: List<OtherSample>
)
```

Result:

```json
{
"time": "2022-01-14",
"name": "name",
"id": 12
"list": 
      [
         {
           "sampleId": 12,
           "value1": value,
           "value2": value,
         },
         {
           "sampleId": 12,
           "value1": value1,
           "value2": value1,
         }
      ]
}
```

What I'd like to achieve is create a list of `ResultDto` where I have time and name from Sample.class and collection of OtherSample.class where id from Sample.class == sampleId from OtherSample.class. It can be few objects.

Has anyone ever had a chance to map something like this?

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly, your problem is with the representation of the classs and the relationship between them. To create such a classs according to the rules, one has to open a master class (father) that will contain the fields common to both and be separated from it. You will then add to each class hair the attributes that suit him.